# Скрипту искать только в определенном div (блоке)

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт [TOC](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/tocjs) который создает оглавление для страницы.
Но на данный момент скрипт обрабатывает всю страницу, как сделать что бы он проверял только определеный блок с каким нибудь классом?

Comment: как ты его используешь?

Comment: На сайте как обычно, прикрепил скрипт и использую.

Comment: нужен пример кода. В вопрос можно [вставить сниппет](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3525/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80/3526#3526) и продемонстрировать как это сейчас работает

Comment: Сделал пример: https://codepen.io/AnatoliyAV/pen/qqjzWX?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

У плагина есть [опция](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/tocjs#usage)

`selector` (default value is h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6): указывает какие элементы будут добавлены в таблицу.

Как можно заметить, значение по умолчанию - список заголовков, но так как в самом коде плагина они выбираются с помощь [`$(this.options.selector)`](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/tocjs/blob/master/src/js/toc.js#L20), то выбраны будут все подходящие элементы на странице.

Чтобы ограничить их, нужно просто поменять значение этой опции.

Например так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toc').toc({
    selector: '#content h1,#content h2,#content h3,#content h4',
    elementClass: 'toc',
    ulClass: 'nav',
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nghuuphuoc/tocjs/master/dist/js/toc.min.js"></script>
<h1>Меня брать не надо</h1>

<div id="content" title="Брать заголовки только из этого блока">
  <h1>Меня надо взять</h1> 
  <p>text text text text text text text text</p>

  <h2>И меня 1</h2>
  <p>text text text text text text text text</p>

  <h3>И меня 2</h3>
  <p>text text text text text text text text</p>

  <h4>И меня тоже 3</h4>
  <p>text text text text text text text text</p>
</div>

<div id="toc"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает, как я сам не додумался :)